OpenBao (Vault): How to solve Permissions warning in logfiles for raft FSM db file
We are using OpenBao (HashiCorp Vault fork) in a Cluster configuration as our vault solution deployed into Kubernetes using the official OpenBao Helm Chart (https://openbao.github.io/openbao-helm) in version 0.5.1.
During startup a warning message shows in the logfiles:
{"@level":"warn","@message":"raft FSM db file has wider permissions than needed","@module":"storage.raft.fsm","@timestamp":"2024-09-21T10:57:37.228270Z","existing":432,"needed":384}

While the meaning of the message is of course clear, we are wondering how this is solved in the best way without manually changing any permissions.
After all this file is generated by OpenBao itself, so it should also set the permissions.
Anybody had this issue before and solved it in an automated way rather than fiddling with permissions manually?
